# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not pulling

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to pull an object from a subdocument in a mongodb. The structure is as follows (from `db.users.find().pretty()`):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56a660b42819b770b89950bd"),
"userName" : "someGuy",
"itemCollection" : [
    {
        "item_name" : "item1",
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a661232819b770b89950be")
    }
],
"__v" : 13
}
```

This code:

```
var userID = req.user._id;
var transactionID = req.body._id;
console.log('userID: '+userID);
console.log('transactionID: '+transactionID);
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    userID,
    {$pull: {'itemCollection': {'_id': transactionID}}},{new: true}, function(err, model){
    if(err){
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    }
    console.log(model);
});
```

Gets me the following output:

```
> userID: 56a660b42819b770b89950bd
> transactionID: 56a661232819b770b89950be
> { itemCollection: 
    [ { item_name: 'item1',
    _id: 56a661232819b770b89950be } ],
__v: 13,
userName: 'someGuy',
_id: 56a660b42819b770b89950bd }
```

So nothing seems to have happened. I've tried every variation on stack overflow that I could find but it never deletes it. Does anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `_id`s from string to an `ObjectID` type:

`var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userID = mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.user._id);`

Comment: omg thank you so much! I must be stupid as this was never specifically mentioned and I never though of this. Ofcourse it is logical in the end...