# how to remove like from array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The only thing I need is to remove the like if the user has already liked the post. I've tried with filter and other methods and it doesn't work.

The add like part is working normally. Like is an Array of objects.

If anyone can help..

```
    const id = req.params.id;

    const post = await Posts.findOne({ _id: id });
    const token = getToken(req);
    const user = await getUserByToken(token);

    post.like = {
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
    };
    const liked = post.like.find((likeExist) => {
      return likeExist._id == user._id;
    });

    if (liked !== undefined) {
      const newLike = await Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(post, {
        $pull: { like: post.like },
      });

      res.status(200).json({
        Likes: newLike.like,
      });
      return
    } else {
      const newLike = await Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(post._id, {
        $push: { like: post.like },
      });

      res.status(200).json({
        Likes: newLike.like,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023866/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-not-pulling solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Posts.findByIdAndUpdate()` and not giving it a proper ID. You could do so:

```js
const newLike = await Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(
   mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(post._id), { $pull: { like: post.like } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an object to a post.like

```
post.like = {
  _id: user._id,
  name: user.name,
};
```

and then using find method on it

```
const liked = post.like.find((likeExist) => {
  return likeExist._id == user._id;
});
```

That doesn't make sense.

Try something like this:

```
const id = req.params.id;

const post = await Posts.findOne({ _id: id });
const user = await getUserByToken(token);


const index = post.like.findIndex((like) => {
    return like._id == user._id;
});

if (index > -1) {
    // already liked, remove it
    post.like.splice(index, 1);
} else {
    // add a like
    post.like.push({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name
    });
}

// no need to use Posts.findByIdAndUpdate
// just save the post
post.save();

res.status(200).json({
    Likes: post.like
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. it keep adding like from the same user